# User does not have CREATE TABLE access to database DBC

Tags: teradata, teradatasql

I am using the **tdload** utility of Teradata to import data into an existing empty table in my database.

The command I'm running is :

```
tdload -h 192.168.xxx.xxx -u dbc -p dbc -f path/to/file.csv 
-t AdventureWorksDW.DemoTable MyJob
```

I get the following error after running the command

```
RDBMS error 3524: The user does not have CREATE TABLE access to database DBC.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Don't use DBC, that's a system database.  Use a database that you have create access to. Work with your DBAs.

Answer (score 0):

Although you defined the AdventureWorksDW as Database for Target Table, the underlying TPT still needs a working database (for temporary / working tables). These temp tables are by default created in you user database (you're using DBC user). You can work on this by either using another user or defining the **"--TargetWorkingDatabase" parameter**.